# How to resample data by clusters (block sampling) with replacement in R using Sampling package

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, resampling

This is my dummy data:

```
income <- as.data.frame.vector <- sample(1000:10000, 1000, replace=TRUE)
individuals <- as.data.frame.vector <- sample(1:50,1000,replace=TRUE)
datatest <- as.data.frame (cbind (income, individuals))
```

I know I can sample by individual rows with this code:

```
sample <- datatest[sample(nrow(datatest), replace=TRUE),]
```

Now, I want to extract random samples with replacement and equal probabilities of the dataset but sampling complete blocks of observations with the same individual code.
Note that there are 50 individuals, but 1000 observations. Some observations belong to the same individual, so I want to sample by individuals (clusters, in this case), not observations. I don't mind if the extracted samples differ slightly in the number of observations. How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
 library(sampling)
 samplecluster <- cluster (datatest, clustername=c("individuals"), size=50,
                           method="srswr")
```

But the outcome is not the sampled data. Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomly select groups (and all cases per group) in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214769/randomly-select-groups-and-all-cases-per-group-in-r)

Comment: Just realised that this must be a very common problem a found a very similar question.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is the same problem. I will leave the question posted however in case someone searches it with this terms. Also, besides your answer and the answers in the other question, I provide below an alternative answer using the Sampling package.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I am missing something. If you just want some of your individuals, you can create a smaller sample of them:

```
ind.sample <- sample(1:50, size = 10)
print(ind.sample)
# [1] 17 43 38 39 28 23 35 47  9 13
my.sample <- datatest[datatest$individuals %in% ind.sample) ,]
head(my.sample)
#    income individuals
#21    9072          17
#97    5928          35
#122   9130          43
#252   4388          43
#285   8083          28
#287   1065          35
```

I guess a more generic approach would be to generate random indexes;

```
ind.unique <- unique(individuals)
ind.sample.index <- sample(1:length(ind.unique), size = 10)
ind.sample <- ind.unique[ind.sample.index]
print(ind.sample[order(ind.sample)])
my.sample <- datatest[datatest$individuals %in% ind.sample, ]
ind.counts <- aggregate(income ~ individuals, my.sample, FUN = length)
print(ind.counts)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems I was indeed missing something. After the `cluster` command you need to apply the `getdata` command (all from the Sampling Package). This way I do get the sample as I wanted, plus some additional columns.

```
samplecluster <- cluster (datatest, clustername=c("personid"), size=50, method="srswr")
```

Gives you:

```
head(samplecluster)

individuals ID_unit Replicates    Prob
1        1     259          2 0.63583
2        1     178          2 0.63583
3        1     110          2 0.63583
4        1     153          2 0.63583
5        1     941          2 0.63583
6        1     667          2 0.63583
```

Then using `getdata`, I also get the original data on income sampled by whole clusters:

```
datasample <- getdata (datatest, samplecluster)

head(datasample)
  income individuals ID_unit Replicates   Prob
1   8567        1     259          2 0.63583
2   2701        1     178          2 0.63583
3   4998        1     110          2 0.63583
4   3556        1     153          2 0.63583
5   2893        1     941          2 0.63583
6   7581        1     667          2 0.63583
```

Comment: Also I found here another straight forward way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214769/randomly-select-groups-and-all-cases-per-group-in-r

Answer (score 1):

I think its important to note that the dataset still needs to be expanded to include all the replicates.

```
sw<-data.frame(datasample[rep(seq_len(dim(datasample)[1]), datasample$Replicates),,  drop = FALSE], row.names=NULL)
```

Might be helpful to someone