# How to random choose 100 countries out of all countries with multiple year panel data in R

Tags: r

I have a panel data, with 200+ countries, for each year from 2007 to 2013, and gdp data for each country in each year.
What I want to is to randomly choose 100 countries and subset the data set with data for only these five countries.
I currently do not have any idea...

````
225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 
236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), .Label = c("ABW", 
"AFG", "AGO", "AIA", "ALA", "ALB", "AND", "ANT", "ARE", "ARG", 
"ARM", "ASM", "ATA", "ATF", "ATG", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BDI", 
"BEL", "BEN", "BFA", "BGD", "BGR", "BHR", "BHS", "BIH", "BLM", 
"BLR", "BLZ", "BMU", "BOL", "BRA", "BRB", "BRN", "BTN", "BVT", 
"BWA", "CAF", "CAN", "CCK", "CHE", "CHL", "CHN", "CIV", "CMR", 
"COD", "COG", "COK", "COL", "COM", "CPV", "CRI", "CUB", "CXR", 
"CYM", "CYP", "CZE", "DEU", "DJI", "DMA", "DNK", "DOM", "DZA", 
"ECU", "EGY", "ERI", "ESH", "ESP", "EST", "ETH", "FIN", "FJI", 
"FLK", "FRA", "FRO", "FSM", "GAB", "GBR", "GEO", "GGY", "GHA", 
"GIB", "GIN", "GLP", "GMB", "GNB", "GNQ", "GRC", "GRD", "GRL", 
"GTM", "GUF", "GUM", "GUY", "HKG", "HMD", "HND", "HRV", "HTI", 
"HUN", "IDN", "IMN", "IND", "IOT", "IRL", "IRN", "IRQ", "ISL", 
"ISR", "ITA", "JAM", "JEY", "JOR", "JPN", "KAZ", "KEN", "KGZ", 
"KHM", "KIR", "KNA", "KOR", "KWT", "LAO", "LBN", "LBR", "LBY", 
"LCA", "LIE", "LKA", "LSO", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MAC", "MAF", 
"MAR", "MCO", "MDA", "MDG", "MDV", "MEX", "MHL", "MKD", "MLI", 
"MLT", "MMR", "MNE", "MNG", "MNP", "MOZ", "MRT", "MSR", "MTQ", 
"MUS", "MWI", "MYS", "MYT", "NAM", "NCL", "NER", "NFK", "NGA", 
"NIC", "NIU", "NLD", "NOR", "NPL", "NRU", "NZL", "OMN", "PAK", 
"PAN", "PCN", "PER", "PHL", "PLW", "PNG", "POL", "PRI", "PRK", 
"PRT", "PRY", "PSE", "PYF", "QAT", "REU", "ROU", "RUS", "RWA", 
"SAU", "SDN", "SEN", "SGP", "SGS", "SHN", "SJM", "SLB", "SLE", 
"SLV", "SMR", "SOM", "SPM", "SRB", "STP", "SUR", "SVK", "SVN", 
"SWE", "SWZ", "SYC", "SYR", "TCA", "TCD", "TGO", "THA", "TJK", 
"TKL", "TKM", "TLS", "TON", "TTO", "TUN", "TUR", "TUV", "TWN", 
"TZA", "UGA", "UKR", "UMI", "URY", "USA", "UZB", "VAT", "VCT", 
"VEN", "VGB", "VIR", "VNM", "VUT", "WLF", "WSM", "YEM", "ZAF", 
"ZMB", "ZWE"), class = "factor"), Date = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L), Log_DMSP = c(NA, 7.46, 8.19, 10.02, NA, 9.26, 
6.31, 5.58, 8.95, NA, 7.6, 13, 8.17, -0.99, 2.77, 9.8, 3.31, 
5.18, 9.09, 3.73, NA, NA, 7.74, 9.73, 6.96, 6.48, 4.8, 6.84, 
7.64, 3.27, 3.98, 6.26, 5.01, 5.22, 9.46, 10.14, 6.43, 3.08, 
NA, NA, 4.51, 9.68, 8.65, 7.48, 4.04, 9.59, 5.72, 5.9, 7.35, 
7.78)), row.names = 221:270, class = "data.frame")```
````

Comment: What do you mean by `What I want to is to randomly choose 100 countries and subset the data set with data for only these five countries`. Do you want to randomly choose 100 countries or 5? Also in the answer you posted you are sampling 200 countries.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved, as I found a great answer to another question!
[Randomly select groups (and all cases per group) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214769/randomly-select-groups-and-all-cases-per-group-in-r)

```r
country <- sample(unique(as.character(NightlightGdp$Country)),200)
NightlightGdp_200 <- NightlightGdp[NightlightGdp$Country %in% country, ]
```

Comment: The link is above

Comment: I learned the approach from the post I mentioned above but the codes provided here is mean to solve my question